# How can I get remote JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a steroids app and it uses angular js. It reads data from a local JSON file and I'm trying to get remote JSON instead. How can I go about doing this? Below is the code contained in my "show.js" file. I've tried changing

```
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/data');
```

with the url to my server JSON but that didn't work either.

```
    (function () {

    // Protects views where angular is not loaded from errors
    if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        return;
    };


    var module = angular.module('ShowModel', ['restangular']);

    module.factory('ShowRestangular', function (Restangular) {

        return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {

            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/data');
            RestangularConfigurer.setRequestSuffix('.json');
            RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
                id: "show_id"
            });

        });

    });


})();
```

Comment: i wonder why don't you use jquery for this ? you can club jquery with angular.js

Comment: Not sure about the AngularJs implementation, but have a look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Have a look at [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).